# Most efficient way of finding dictionary values by (a larg list) of keys? Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, performance, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

`d = {"sadsa": 4, "awdwa" 13, ,"tdadq": 2  ...}`  composed of 100000 items

Now I have a list of around 1000 items: `l = ["awdwa", "fdafs", ...]`

What is the fastest way to retrieve all matching values?

Currently, I'm trying the following method:

- `[d[i] for i in l if i in d]`

Is there a faster way?

I read something about ordering, but I'm not sure what it means. Is it related to binary search?

How does the dictionary get value by key, works ... does it iterate through all keys until finding the matching one?

Comment: This is efficient, dict objects get values from keys in constant time, unless there is catastrophic hash collision. In most practical cases what you are doing is as efficient as you are going to get

Comment: "How does the dictionary get value by key, works ... does it iterate through all keys until finding the matching one?" No, dict objects are implemented as hash tables